# How to put the ALT-value of an image into a variable in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve made a cardspread program that is based on the source of the image. It works allright, but it is loading slowly, because now 78 different cards are loaded. I like to speed up the loading and I thought I needed an extra item per DIV. So I added an ALT-tag to each image. Like this:

```
<div id="kaart1">
   <alt=kaart14.jpg>
       <img src="images/kaart1.jpg" width="110" height="180" onclick="showDiv(event)>
   </alt=kaart14.jpg>
</div>
```

Now I need only 1 image to load 78 times, which is faster. The problem which I am facing now is that I want to read the alt value into a variable (in this case: kaart14.jpg).
I’ve tried :

```
 $('.status').click(function() {
            var status = $(this).attr('alt');
            });
```

But that stays empty. Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this in Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: what element does have the `status` class?

Answer (score 1):

Your `alt` attribute should be like

```
<div id="kaart1">
   <img src="images/kaart1.jpg" alt="kaart Image" width="110" height="180" onclick="showDiv(event)>
</div>
```

`alt` is an attribute of the `img` tag,its not a tag itself.And as @Bergi said,the `alt` attribute will not be an another image.It may be the **description**.

Comment: However, the value of the `alt` attribute should not be the image url

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no `<alt>` tag. It is used as alternative to `<img>`. The value is displayed if the image is not loaded.

It is just plain text. If you put a url there, it will just display the url and not the image itself.

Eg:

```
<img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="This is my photo">
```

There is no performance gain if you use alt or not, but you definitely SEO